# JS won't apply to second 'id' if first 'id' is on a different page

Tags: javascript

I have two HTML documents that both have the same .js script linked just before the /body tag. On the JS document, the top IIFE is linked to an 'id' on one page, and it works fine, but when I go to the second page, the IIFE that is linked to that 'id' won't work. However, when I flip the positions of the IIFEs on the JS doc, the 2nd one (now on top) works and the other one doesn't...

```
//one
var loop = (function () {
  'use strict';
   var array = [5, 10, 15, 20],
    length = array.length,
    levelNumber = 0,
    tell = '',
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    levelNumber = (i + 1);
    tell += 'Level ' + levelNumber + ': ';
    tell += array[i] + '<br/>';
    document.getElementById('loop').innerHTML = tell;
    }
}());


 //two
   var multiple = (function () {
     'use strict';
      var level = 1,
      msg;

      switch (level) {
      case 1:
        msg = 'ONE!';
        break;
      case 2:
        msg = 'TWO!';
        break;
      }
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = msg;

  }());
```

Comment: What are the `loop` and `multiple` variables for? Won't they both be `undefined` given that neither function returns anything explicitly?

Comment: Anything DOM related should probably be done in an `onready` block, or a jQuery style `$(function() { .... })`. What does your debugger say? Also you can `'use strict'` once in a file at the top. There's no need to keep putting that in there. If you're really concerned about strictness, use a JavaScript linter set to a very aggressive level of whine.

Comment: Ya I guess that's just how I saw it done before. These don't need to be stored in variables. Taking them away didn't change anything, though =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element doesn't exist on the page then `document.getElementById('loop')` will return `null`, and trying to do `null.innerHTML` will give an error and stop your script from continuing. (If you look in your browser's console you should see the error there.)

Try testing for `null` (i.e., testing whether the elements exist), perhaps something like this at the beginning of each function:

```
var el = document.getElementById('loop');
if (!el) return;
```

In context:

```js
var loop = (function () {
  'use strict';
   var el = document.getElementById('loop');
   if (!el) return;
   var array = [5, 10, 15, 20],
    length = array.length,
    levelNumber = 0,
    tell = '',
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    levelNumber = (i + 1);
    tell += 'Level ' + levelNumber + ': ';
    tell += array[i] + '<br/>';
    el.innerHTML = tell;
    }
}());

//two
var multiple = (function () {
     'use strict';
      var el = document.getElementById('test');
      if (!el) return;
      var level = 1,
      msg;

      switch (level) {
      case 1:
        msg = 'ONE!';
        break;
      case 2:
        msg = 'TWO!';
        break;
      }
      el.innerHTML = msg;

}());
```

```html
<p>For this demo, only the "test" element exists, but the second function should work because the first function checks for existence of "loop"...</p>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Or you could test at the point where you're about to assign the value:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
if (el) {
  el.innerHTML = msg;
}
```

...but given that the functions seem to have no purpose except to update the element there's no point doing the calculations if the element isn't there.

As an aside, your `loop` and `multiple` variables will both end up with the value `undefined` because neither IIFE includes a `return` statement.

Comment: It worked! Wow, you're amazing. Thank you so much. So every time I create an IIFE, I'll have to put that null test at the beginning to allow for the relevant code to work?

Comment: Whether it's an IIFE or not is irrelevant. You need a null test whenever the element might not exist at the time the code runs.